# python regex: How can I have pattern searching for multiple pattern strings?

Tags: python, regex

I have to search the following patterns in a file, (any match qualifies)

```
pattern_strings = ['\xc2d', '\xa0', '\xe7', '\xc3\ufffdd', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc3\xa7', '\xa0\xa0', '\xc2', '\xe9']
pattern = [re.compile(x) for x in pattern_strings]
```

and function using this

```
def find_pattern(path):
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            found = pattern.search(line)
            if found:
                logging.info('found - ' + found)
```

When I try using it

```
find_pattern('myfile')
```

I see `AttributeError: "'list' object has no attribute 'search'"`

because patterns is

`[<_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x107948378>, <_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x107b31c70>, <_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x107b31ce0>, <_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x107ac3cb0>, <_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x107b747b0>, <_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x107b74828>, <_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x107b748a0>, <_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x107b31d50>, <_sre.SRE_Pattern object at 0x107b31dc0>]`

How can I have one pattern which looks for all strings in `pattern_strings`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply concatenate all the expressions together with a `|`:

```
pattern_strings = ['\xc2d', '\xa0', '\xe7', '\xc3\ufffdd', '\xc2\xa0', '\xc3\xa7', '\xa0\xa0', '\xc2', '\xe9']
pattern_string = '|'.join(pattern_strings)
pattern = re.compile(pattern_string)
```

This does, however, assume that none of your patterns are complicated enough that a simple concatenation like this might break.  For the ones in your example, it should work.  For more complex patterns, it may not.

Comment: you should also sort the list longest to shortest... otherwise you will get not the results you expect..